# How do I put conditionals in makefile pattern rules?

Tags: makefile

I have an included file for a makefile that has these rules:

```
$(OUT_DIR)/%.0: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -E -P $< -o $(OUT_DIR)/$<.preproc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -E -dD $< -o $(OUT_DIR)/$<.macros
```

Works great. But, for some targets, I only want this:

```
$(OUT_DIR)/%.0: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

can I do something like this using a predefined (or command line) variable:

```
$(OUT_DIR)/%.0: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
    ifeq ($(CIFLAG), 1)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -E -P $< -o $(OUT_DIR)/$<.preproc
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -E -dD $< -o $(OUT_DIR)/$<.macros
    endif
```

I'm sure I can include a different file based on the CIFLAG value, but was hoping I could do it by modifying the pattern rule.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

I did as MadScientist suggested (thanks for the education) but don't get what I want. My file now appears as:

```
$(OUT_DIR)/%.0: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
    [ $(CI_BUILD) -eq 0 ] \
        || {$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -E -P $< -o $(OUT_DIR)/$<.preproc \
        && $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -E -dD $< -o $(OUT_DIR)/$<.macros; }
```

But, when I execute, I get this (lots of irrelevant output trimmed):

```
cc -c -o test.o
[ 1 -eq 0 ] \
     || {cc -E -P test.c -o test.c.preproc \
     && cc -E -dD test.c -o test.c.macros; }

/bin/sh: -c: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token '}'
```

Is the ';' a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mustn't indent the Make conditional with tabs:

```
$(OUT_DIR)/%.0: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
ifeq ($(CIFLAG), 1)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -E -P $< -o $(OUT_DIR)/$<.preproc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -E -dD $< -o $(OUT_DIR)/$<.macros
endif
```

See bullet 4: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recipe-Syntax.html

Comment: This will work if `CIFLAG` is set globally but won't work if `CIFLAG` is set only in the target context.  The question doesn't specify how it will be set.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use make conditionals like `ifeq` in the recipe passed to the shell, because the shell runs the recipe not make.  You can use shell conditionals:

```
$(OUT_DIR)/%.0: %.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
        [ ($(CIFLAG) -ne 1 ] \
          || { $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -E -P $< -o $(OUT_DIR)/$<.preproc \
               && $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -E -dD $< -o $(OUT_DIR)/$<.macros; }
```

Of course, you haven't discussed how you plan to set the `CIFLAG` variable for some targets but not others...

Comment: Darn. Still not working. I updated the original issue with what happens now. ANd, the pattern rule is in an included file. The variable gets set prior to including the file. :-)

Comment: You took out the space between the `{` and the compiler, that I had in my example.  If you put it back, it will work.

Comment: You can use Make conditionals in a recipe, but you mustn't indent them with a tabs. See bullet 4: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recipe-Syntax.html

Comment: That's true, but you cannot check variables which depend on the specific rule (that won't be set until the recipe is being invoked).  That's why I said _you haven't discussed how you plan to set the `CIFLAG` variable_.  Depending on how it's set you have different options.  This result will work no matter how you do it: target-specific variables, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work by changing the code to:

```
$(OUT_DIR)/%.0: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
    if [ ($(CIFLAG) -ne 1 ]; then \
      $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -E -P $< -o $(OUT_DIR)/$<.preproc; \
      $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -E -dD $< -o $(OUT_DIR)/$<.macros; fi
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it doesn't propagate the error checking properly: for example if the creation of the `preproc` file fails this rule will not notice that.